# How can we make the most of a cramming session?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, long-term-memory, metacognition

While spaced repetition would be ideal, if we are forced into a situation requiring cramming, how can we maximize the short term benefit?

Consider a hypothetical scenario: I am locked in an isolated room with a stack of flashcards. After an indeterminate amount of time, I will be administered a test of the material on the flashcards.

What would the best approach to studying the flashcards? Is there an optimal way to schedule the order of the cards as I review them?

It seems like everyone acknowledges the reality of cramming under current educational practices, so what can we do to make the most of it?

Comment: A starting point maybe: Glenn, D. (2007). Why Cramming Doesn't Work. Chronicle of Higher Education, 53(40). https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ771779  and   Kornell, N. (2009). Optimising learning using flashcards: Spacing is more effective than cramming. Applied Cognitive Psychology: The Official Journal of the Society for Applied Research in Memory and Cognition, 23(9), 1297-1317. https://doi.org/10.1002/acp.1537

Comment: @TonyMobbs Very interesting - thanks!